# MFC CEdit - Painting the Background at a Portion of Length

Tags: c++, mfc, cedit

I would like to have a CEdit control, background-painted half-length or in any other portion of its length.

I have implemented the following code

```
    HBRUSH CMyView::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
    {
        HBRUSH hbr = CFormView::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
    
        if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_EDIT)
        {
    
            if (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_MY_NORMAL_PERCENT_BOX)
            {
                // Set the text color to red
                pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    
                CRect rc;
                // Get the client area of the edit control
                m_CTV_Normal_Percent_Box_Ctrl.GetClientRect(&rc);
                m_CTV_Normal_Percent_Box_Ctrl.ScreenToClient(&rc);
                // Apply the device context to the client area of the edit control
                pDC->Rectangle(0, 0, rc.Width()/2, rc.Height());
    
                // Set the background mode for text to transparent 
                // so background will show thru.
                pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
    
                // Return handle to our CBrush object
                hbr = m_brush;
    
            }
        }

        return hbr;
    }
```

but this could not be achieved. Could anyone possibly assist?

This is what I would like to get

[image]

and this is what I get

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I have failed"* is not a problem statement.

Comment: have just amended the question and the politically incorrect statement.

Comment: IInspectable's complaint was not about the wording, but about the fact that it doesn't tell us *what* is failing. Does it paint at all? Does it crash? *How* does it fail?  *"this could not be achieved"* tells us nothing more than your first wording.

Comment: it paints the whole edit control but not a portion of it. I just want to paint, i.e. 60 percent of the length, corresponding to some statistics.

Comment: @DevMat maybe you should post a _picture_ of what you get vs what you want

Comment: have just updated the question

Comment: Don't you need to make your edit control owner draw and render it yourself?

Comment: @Andrew Truckle, do you mean a solution like this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/646482/Custom-Controls-in-Win-API-Control-Customization

Comment: Maybe. Have you investigated the erasebackground handler? It could possibly be wiping what you are drawing?